# Is there a way to turn CSS elipsis dots into a link?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to turn CSS elipsis dots into a link ?

Something like

```
text text text text... (The three dots should show up as a link). I read an answer and found that this was not doable. So I managed with substring Operation on paragraph and then wrapping '...' inside <a>tag. Thanks for all your asnwers
```

Answer (score 2):

**There is no way of turning the ellipsis dots into a link (if you are using the text-overflow styling).**

However `<a>` (link) elements are inline elements - so will naturally follow on from whatever text you have... .so the simplest approach would be to append an `<a>` element to the end of the text... (note that I am using the html entity (`&#8230;`) of an ellipsis - rather than simply 3 dots....

However - **this is not really advisable from an accessibility or user experience stand point**.... an `<a>` element is used to take the user to another location - not  really to act as a house for the ellipsis .... and here is nothibng to tell the user that there is a link there - nor what happens when you click it.

A Far better approach would be a dedicated and obvious link element - or a show more / show less button at the end of the text... and yes - I say a button...

A link should take the user to another location or context .. .and a button (which can be styled to look like a link) is used to alter the content or perform a function in the same location or context.
Using the right HTMLelement for the right job is important... and so is understanding the outcome of coding choices... you would need to have a good reason to make an ellipsis  the link text - and not simply as a show-more... IMO

```css
p, a { 
color: #222;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p>text text text text <a href="abc">&#8230;</a></p>
```